# No applicable constructor/method found for zero actual parameters - Apache Spark Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have been facing strange error with my spark job at runtime. I don't see anything wrong with `MyBean` class, any idea what could be wrong with below driver code? Thanks

**Maven Dependencies-**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**Driver-**

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate();
spark.createDataset(Arrays.asList(new MyBean(10),new MyBean(20)),
      Encoders.bean(MyBean.class)).show();
```

.....

```
class MyBean implements Serializable {
    int i;
    public MyBean(){}
    public MyBean(int i){this.i=i;}
    public int getI() {return i;}
    public void setI(int i) {this.i = i;}
}
```

Runtime Exception-

> ERROR
>    org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException:org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator
>   org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java',
>   Line 43,  Column 21: No applicable constructor/method found for zero
>   actual parameters;  candidates are: "public int
>   com.ts.spark.datasets.MyBean.getI()"  at
>   org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.compileError(UnitCompiler.java:11004)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.findMostSpecificIInvocable(UnitCompiler.java:8307)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.findIMethod(UnitCompiler.java:8169)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.janino.UnitCompiler.findIMethod(UnitCompiler.java:8071)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Spark needs public JavaBean class. It looks like you are defining the `MyBean` class in the same class where you are creating `SparkSession`. There are two options to resolve this issue. First option is - Create a separate class file for `MyBean.java` public class.

```
public class MyBean implements Serializable {
    int i;
    //Getters and Setters
}
```

Second option is - Define `MyBean` as public static inner class of your main class like below.

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkSession spark = ...;
    }

    public static class MyBean implements Serializable {
        int i;  
        //Getters and Setters
    }
}
```

Comment: For me this only works when I define all data members as String, if I define Integer or int, then he cannot find the right setter.. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a similar error when my class definition was missing with default constructor.

Adding the code below worked for me -

```
public myclass() {}
```